# Does the other person know that you have blocked them in xbox live?

Tags: xbox-network

I occasionally get abusive messages on xbox, if my opponent deems that I have had a lucky win on Fifa for instance. I tend to just block them, but does the other user know that I have blocked them, or do they merrily live their lives without knowing this devastating option has been unleashed on them?

Comment: I think it's like they don't know until they try to contact you again and they get a "you've been blocked" type message, not too sure though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The person you have blocked has no idea that they are blocked. They can still send you a message/invite but you will never receive it. The original sender gets no message or indication that they are blocked.

Comment: Thanks. Follow on question here. I want to change players behaviour! http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92897/effect-of-xbox-player-reviews

Answer (score 3):

You can clearly see that you have been blocked on Xbox.com. Log in through that website and try sending that person an Add Friend submission. It will clearly state if you have been blocked.

For example, I'm seeing the exact message as I have been blocked by someone. So, if you have been blocked by another user, you will see it. On the Xbox One, you can't see any indications of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear when you get blocked because you can't even see what they are playing anymore 'offline' either status offline or blocked.

Comment: But this isn't a surefire way to know if someone blocked you.  They could be offline because their subscription expired, or they actually are offline, or they have their status set to offline.

Answer (score 0):

You know when your blocked when you try to send someone a friend request again and it says please try again later but not blocked and they never answer your messages but you can answer theirs. Basically, Blocking is kind of a way of turning all your notifications off so nothing appears in your screen saying “New massage from ” or a party or game invite. Also, just to add a little information of muting, when you are muted, you basically can’t talk to the other person at all and I think that even effects headsets. Back to blocking. The not worry about blocking is if you have another friend who’s friends with the blocker, they can tell them all the things you want to say to the blocker. I got blocked by a friend and this is what I expect.