# Effect of Xbox player reviews?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

What effect does an xbox player review have on the reviewed player - does their rep or gamerscore change? Do they see the submitted review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A person's rep is somehow affected by player reviews (except where noted in the player review - for instance, avoiding someone due to their skill does not effect rep), although the exact algorithm is very unclear.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live) that if you've got no reputation, but then you get a 'preferred' from at least one player, your rep will eventually default to 5 stars.  One assumes that a chain of negative player reviews will, over time, decrease this star count.  I've had only a couple of positive reviews and several negative ones (apparently I "trash talk" from time to time!) but my rep has stayed steady at 5 stars for as long as I've been interested in checking.

You can see the feedback you've gotten from others, broken down into percentages, from your profile.  I can't find a place this is given on the Xbox website, but you can get to your profile from the furthest right "slice" in the Xbox Guide menu.

Player reviews also are taken into account when in multiplayer matchmaking, although avoiding a player is not always enough to ensure that you'll never be matched with them again in the future.  I believe this is just one aspect of a much larger algorithm used for matchmaking.

There's no gamerscore impact for reputation, and note that submitting a player review and/or a player's reputation is a separate system from filing a complaint.  The complaint system is the system that can lead to suspensions and so forth.  It is intended for abusive players or those who are glitching or hacking their Xboxes.

Comment: Thanks - didn't know about the rep breakdown in the profile. Mine has 45% avoid me - seems high, I thought I was a model player!

Comment: @thebunk, I get the impression that 99% of people don't leave a review at all.  I've probably played with thousands of people, though it's clear from my percentages that about 3 have left feedback.

Comment: I play a lot too, which is why I'm so surprised by the high %age of players that apparently avoid me. Though the actual %age is 75% unsporting, 25% quit early, so maybe only 4 people have rated me, and the 45% figure is a red herring.

Comment: @thebunk I believe that number is broken.  Mine says 53% prefer or did not submit a review, 47% avoid.  Considering I play a lot, and the feedback system is super cumbersome, I can't believe I have that many avoids.  The only negatives I have are 30% Unsporting and 38% Quit Early - which doesn't add up either.

Comment: @agent86 I just tested positive feedback on some 3 star friends, and it takes more than 1 to get 5 stars.  That said, I think it take a LOT of negative feedback to lose stars.  I have seen folks with less than 3 before though (rarely).

Comment: @EBongo, the wikipedia entry says that if you've got no feedback and you're left a positive one, you'll "eventually" default at 5.  I agree that it probably takes quite a bit of negative feedback (or perhaps within some certain time period?) to get this number lowered.

Answer (score 0):

Player reviews/complaints affect the player itself if anything.

> For example, let's say I am reviewing you:
>
> If I submit a request to "Prefer This Player" towards you, I am most
>   likely to play with you again later on.
>
> If I "Avoid This Player" chances are, I will not be paired up with you
>   again during multiplayer.

If you have a complaint against another player, depending on what they did, and the consequences of the so called offense, it can potentially threaten the Xbox Live account itself.

Player reputation will be effected depending on how many people avoid, or prefer the player. This can be found inside your account section/reputation.

Gamerscore is never effected during any of the above. If your account is banned, then basically your Gamerscore is gone as well until you get your account resolved.

Source: [Xbox Live FAQ](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live/account-banning-and-player-feedback/chat-terms-of-use-conduct), and personal experience.